# git: can I checkout a hotfix branch in a dev environment(with an unmerged dev branch) or will that cross branches?

Tags: linux, git

I'm new to having git set up for multiple users. I typically used it by myself with only one branch. I have a questions that I couldn't find safe answer to via Google:

If I'm currently pulling a feature development branch into my dev server to test the feature and I suddenly discover the need for a hotfix can I re-branch(checkout) the hotfix branch (part of master not dev), pull the files in and start working on/testing a hotfix or will my next "git add ." add the files from the feature branch(which are still on the server) to the hotfix branch therefore mixing the two branches?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, I think your asking if, having changes on the development branch, and then switch to a hot fix branch, will the changes get intermixed with the new branch?

Typically, what I would do is use "git stash save" of any changes on the development branch, checkout the hot fix branch and dothe changes and commit, switch back to the development branch, and then "git stash pop..." To get the development changes back.

You can do "git status" after each step to ensure the working area has what you expect.

Comment: When I use "git stash save" I get a message that says "No local changes to save. My question is close to what you've answered in your response. Because I can still see the files I've edited and committed on development when I switch to hotfix, I worry that pushing will include the development files.

Comment: OK. I think I may know what's up. FYI, the stash is intended to squirrel away changes that have **not** be committed yet, so you don't lose them, when you switch. I think the issue is that you created the hotfix branch, while on the dev branch, so it is based off that and not master. Try creating a new hotfix branch, after first switching to master.

Comment: I'm assuming you are creating the hotfix branch and not switching to an existing branch, BTW.